# grepping with "shopt -s globstar extglob"

Tags: bash, wildcards

I have `shopt -s globstar extglob` in my `./bashrc`. I'm searching for files that refer to  string `Foo` in the following command:

```
grep -Fwn Foo /**/src/**/*.@(h|cpp)
```

Now I want to except all refers from files `Foo.h` and `Foo.cpp`. The following is the command that gain this goal

```
grep -Fwn Foo /**/src/**/*.@(h|cpp) | grep -v Foo.h | grep -v Foo.cpp
```

I'd like to make it without piping command using `!` and `&` in location pattern. I mean something like the following

```
grep -Fwn Foo /**/src/**/@(*.@(h|cpp)&(!(Foo.*)))
```

Why the command from above do not work and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply because there's no such thing as a `&(...)` operator in `bash`. `bash` only implements a subset of `ksh` patterns with `extglob`. Here you want:

```
grep -Fwn Foo /**/src/**/!(Foo).@(h|cpp)
```

With `ksh93`, you can use `&` this way:

```
grep -Fwn Foo /**/src/@(*.@(h|cpp)&!(Foo*))
```

`zsh` has a and-not operator with `extendedglob`:

```
grep -Fwn Foo /**/src/(*.(h|cpp)~Foo*)
```